# SQL gestion de duplicados

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

resulta que tengo que hacer una consulta en la cual se me devuelven varios registros duplicados, salvo por un campo que es contadores.

La cuestion en si es que necesito recoger el registro con el valor de contadores mas alto. Ahora mismo la sentencia es la siguiente

```
SELECT * FROM Bares B inner JOIN Contadores C on B.idProd = C.idLocal where B.EmpresaOperadora='B'
```

Lo que me devuelve 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esos 3 registros, deberia sacarme primero ya que no esta repetido y el ultimo ya que es el repetido con mayor valor de contadoresEntradas. 
Entiendo que debe ser una cosa facil, pero no estoy muy puesto en este tema y de lo que he probado no ha habido buen resultado. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la clave está en la función MAX, es una función de agregado y por ejemplo combinada con GROUP BY creo que pueda ayudarte con esta consulta.

[Link](http://basededatos.umh.es/sql/sql04.htm#MAXMIN)

Por otro lado, para que tengas un ejemplo que te pueda servir, yo retocaría tu consulta de este modo:

```
SELECT idProd, nombreBar, Maquina, MAX(contadoresEntradasAnteriores) FROM Bares B inner JOIN Contadores C on B.idProd = C.idLocal where B.EmpresaOperadora='B
GROUP BY idProd, nombreBAR, Maquina
```

Espero que te sirva al menos de orientación